# Unable to view comments in Imgur

Tags: imgur

I have uploaded an image on imgur and in stats I see that there are 13 comments for that picture. But I do not see any of those comments. What is going on? Where do I see the comments?

[image: Image stats showing 13 comments]

Comment: Got a link to the image?

Comment: Yup. http://imgur.com/gallery/4ovO13C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login
2. Hover over your name, go into gallery profile
3. Then click Submitted images. You should see your stuff there.
4. Click on the picture, and read away!